# I want to change 17k addresses password on ubuntu server

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have 17k ethereum addresses. I want to change passphrase all of them. Are there any way to change all addresses passphrase?

geth account update 0x... It is really hard to change 17k addresses password. I need suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a python script that take all the files in a folder,

```
def find_keystores():
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(keystorepath) if isfile(join(keystorepath, f))]
        counter = 0
        accounts = []
        for file in onlyfiles:
            accounts.append(onlyfiles[counter])
            counter = counter + 1
        return accounts
```

then iterate through them and decrypt it with the current passphrase using web3py

```
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(keystorepath) if isfile(join(keystorepath, f))]
with open(keystorepath + "/" +onlyfiles[0]) as keyfile:
        encrypted_key = keyfile.read()
        private_key = w3.eth.account.decrypt(encrypted_key, passphrase)
```

After you have extracted the private key, you recreate the keystore

```
keystore = w3.eth.account.encrypt(private_key, new_passphrase)
```

This is valid also in other languages (nodejs, rust), the concept is the same.
Just know that the decryption and the encryption of keystore files consume a lot of cpu resources.